# How to disable blinking of the red microphone icon in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, icons, gui, accessibility

I have 64-bit Firefox 80.0.1 for Linux. It features a red blinking microphone icon in the tray on the left of the address bar in certain circumstances. How to disable the blinking and make it a static image (bonus question: and make it look different to what the icon looks like when not blinking if (actually I'm not sure) such state exists and indicates some other circumstances)? It's a huge distraction for me (and possibly for lots of people with certain other disabilities).

Answer (score 0):

Does [this](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1209895) help at all? its from the firefox official forum.

> Hi smalltheif, there is no built-in way to remove that icon.
>
> You can use a custom style rule in a userChrome.css file to hide it or
> to make it more transparent. I haven't experimented with this myself,
> but here are a couple resources if you want to give it a try:
>
> ```
> https://www.reddit.com/r/firefox/comments/78pjz1/how_do_i_remove_this_microphone_indicator/
> https://www.userchrome.org/how-create-userchrome-css.html
> ```

Comment: Please [edit] the answer include essential parts of the solution and then link to original source. Otherwise it may become useless if the link goes bad.

Comment: sorry but i aint jackin a playas steez

Comment: Thanks, it's useful, I might add some transparency to that one.

But I had in mind a different icon. It's in the tray on the left of the address bar. I don't mind it being there, just blinking.

And in Firefox 82.0.2 the blinking red microphone appears on the tab too.